# Implementation of groups in the linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, group, privileges, authorization

### Question:

Are there any further sources to catch up on the **implementation of groups in the linux kernel**.

---

The `man` page about `credentials` helped me out so far, but I like to delve deeper (though still in a way more abstract than reading the source code of the kernel itself).